# filter of Kendo UI grid angular 2

Tags: angular, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I want dropdown filter in my data table like this:

[image]

I have used data table of [kendo UI with multi-column headers.](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/headers/)

anyone having any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its difficult do understand what the problem you have got. But apparently you need to look at the `kendoGridFilterCellTemplate`

```
<kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="Units In Stock" [width]="300" [locked]="false">              
                <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
                        <select>
                        <option value="1">0.33</option>
                        <option value="2">0.32</option>
                        <option value="3">0.73</option>
                      </select>
                     </ng-template>                  
                </kendo-grid-column>
```

plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/aDKZ4hbLOlZ8DqD7bzyn?p=preview